# MongoDB Replica Set and URL server ordering

Tags: node.js, mongodb, connection, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

I am using nodejs and I have a connection URL:

```
config.mongodb.url = 'mongodb://test-mongodb-2,test-mongodb-1,test-mongodb-3:27017/test_db?replicaSet=test_rs';
```

If test-mongodb-2 is not the primary, the connection fails with:

```
not master and slaveOk=false
```

I am using the latest version of the driver: 2.1.21

Is there an option that I am missing?

Comment: Have you double-checked the health of the replicaset (`rs.status()`), and the connectivity between your client and each node of the replicaset?

Comment: Yep, everything works fine as long as the primary is listed first in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Found that there was another piece of code that was causing the problem.